# SSRS Bar chart gradient color depending on value

Tags: charts, reporting-services

i need to set a gradient color depending of the percentage value of the bar. For example: -10% light grey 40% grey 70% dark grey...etc increasing grey for example, i insert a picture of what i want: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlHOa.png)

Comment: First result I found when searching ....

http://sqljason.com/2013/02/custom-code-for-color-gradation-in-ssrs.html

Comment: I want to do a white to black gradient depending on percentage, i looked at it but i think it cant help me, thanks anyway

Comment: That's what that link will allow you to do. You pass in a hex shade of grey (or black or white such as #888888 or #FFFFFF or #000000 and that code will adjust the shade based on the numeric value you pass.